# what is "capability query" in dynamic_cast context and why is this useful?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I am reading some C++ material on dynamic_cast and there the following practice is considered bad:

```
class base{};
class derived1 d1 :public base{};
class derived2 d2 :public base
{
public:
void foo(){}
};
void baz(base *b)
{
    if (derived2 *d2= dynamic_cast<derived2 *> (b) )
    {
     d2-> foo();
    }
}
```

The remedy to this is to use the "capability query" using an empty pure virtual base class like following:

```
class capability_query
{
public:
    virtual void foo()= 0;
};

class base{};
class derived1 d1 :public base{};
class derived2 d2 :public base, public capability_query
{
public:
    virtual void foo(){}
};
void baz(base *b)
{
    if (capability_query *cq= dynamic_cast<capability_query *> (b) )
    {
      cq-> foo();
    }
}
```

My 1st question is why is the first code block considered bad?
The way I see it `foo` is only executed if d2 can be successfully downcasted from b in the `baz` function. So what is the issue here?!

My 2nd question is why is the second code block considered good? and how does this fix the issue, which I don't understand in the first place.

FYI, my google search for `capability query` returned http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Capability_Query
which seems to be basically code block1 and not code block2. I still don't get why an additional empty base class is considered a better practice?

**EDIT:**
here is the best possible answer I can think of.Since inside `baz` I am downcasting to a pointer type and not reference, in case the downcast is not successful , I will get a Null pointer and not std::bad_cast. So, assuming the cast goes wrong and I do get NULL pointer , but what if I am not supposed to execute `Null->foo` and if I may forget to test for NULL, so code block 1 could be a problem.
The way code block 2 fixes this, is by adding an empty class. Even if

```
dynamic_cast<capability_query *> (b)
```

fails and I get a null pointer , you cannot execute 
`null->foo` since inside `capability_query` class this `foo` method is pure virtual. This is just a conjecture , but may be I am on the right path??!!

Comment: This question is probably too subjective, but the first block is not considered bad and the second is overkill in this situation. With that said, I've done a lot of C++ and this is the first time I've heard of this idiom.

Comment: It is not possible for parent class know what methods its subclass have. So I think second approach is not practical

Answer (score 1):

The academic answer would be that in *object oriented design* you should not depend on the *implementation* i.e. concrete classes. Instead you should depend on high-level components like *interfaces* and *abstract base classes*. You can read more about this [design principle on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

The reason for this is to *decouple* the design which makes the code more manageable and maintainable.

Let's look at an example. You have a base class and a derived class:

```
struct Duck {
    virtual ~Duck() {}
};

struct MallardDuck : public Duck {
    void quack() const {
        std::cout << "Quack!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Let's say you have another class with a function taking a parameter `Duck`.

```
struct SoundMaker {
    void makeSound(const Duck* d) {
        if (const MallardDuck* md = dynamic_cast<const MallardDuck*>(d)) {
            md->quack();
        }
    }
};
```

You can use the classes like this:

```
MallardDuck md;
SoundMaker sm;
sm.makeSound(&md);
```

Which outputs `Quack!`.
Now lets add another derived class `RubberDuck`:

```
struct RubberDuck : public Duck {
    void squeak() const {
        std::cout << "Squeak!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

If you want `SoundMaker` to use the class `RubberDuck` you must make changes in `makeSound`:

```
void makeSound(const Duck* d) {
    if (const MallardDuck* md = dynamic_cast<const MallardDuck*>(d)) {
        md->quack();
    } else if (const RubberDuck* rd = dynamic_cast<const RubberDuck*>(d)) {
        rd->squeak();
    }
}
```

What if you need to add another type of duck and produce its sound? For every new type of duck you add, you will have to make changes in both the code of the new duck class and in `SoundMaker`. This is because you depend on concrete implementation. Wouldn't it be better if you could just add new ducks without having to change `SoundMaker`? Look at the following code:

```
struct Duck {
    virtual ~Duck() {}
    virtual void makeSound() const = 0;
};

struct MallardDuck : public Duck {
    void makeSound() const override {
        quack();
    }

    void quack() const {
        std::cout << "Quack!" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct RubberDuck : public Duck {
    void makeSound() const override {
        squeak();
    }

    void squeak() const {
        std::cout << "Squeak!" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct SoundMaker {
    void makeSound(const Duck* d) {
        d->makeSound(); // No dynamic_cast, no dependencies on implementation.
    }
};
```

Now you can use both duck types in the same way as before:

```
MallardDuck md;
RubberDuck rd;
SoundMaker sm;
sm.makeSound(&md);
sm.makeSound(&rd);
```

And you can add as many duck types as you wish without having to change anything in `SoundMaker`. This is a *decoupled design* and is much easier to maintain. *This is the reason for why it is bad practise to down-cast and depend on concrete classes*, instead only use high-level interfaces (in the general case).

In your second example you're using a separate class to evaluate if the requested behaviour of the derived class is available. This might be somewhat better as you separate (and *encapsulate*) the behaviour-control code. It still creates dependencies to your implementation though and every time the implementation changes you may need to change the behaviour-control code.

Comment: not sure this is what OP ask for, you are just saying "use polymorphism"

Comment: @BryanChen What I'm trying to say is that when you have to `dynamic_cast` to a concrete type you may have a bad design. I tried to show an example where you didn't have that dependency (and you could do the same thing without down-casting).

Answer (score 1):

The first example, where foo is called on  `d2->foo()`, violates the Open-Closed Principle, which in this case means that you should be able to add or remove functionality in `d2` without changing code in `baz` (or anywhere else).  The code:

```
void baz(base *b)
{
    if (capability_query *cq= dynamic_cast<capability_query *> (b) )
    {
      cq-> foo();
    }
}
```

shows that `baz` depends on the definition of the class `d2`. If one day, the function  `d2::foo()` is removed, the function `baz` will also have to be modified, otherwise you'll be a compiler error.

However, in the improved version, if an author decides to remove the `foo` capability of d2 by removing the base class `capability_query`, (or indeed if the `foo` capability were to be added to class `d1`) the function `baz` needs no modification, and the run time behavior will automatically be correct.